# Produce HTML table in R: Column.labels or dep.var.caption on table of data frame in stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I have a data frame that is effectively stored regression results, with relevant values as columns and variables as rows (each stored in names). It looks something like this:

```
a <- c(3, 0.5, 0.010, 4, 0.3, 0.271)
b <- c(10, 0.9, 0.021, 8, 0.5, 0.063)
temp <- data.frame(rbind(b, a))
colnames(temp) <- c("Coef", "SE", "p-value", "Coef", "SE", "p-value")
rownames(temp) <- c("alpha", "bravo")
```

Using `stargazer`, I'd like to create an HTML table that presents this information and allows me to identify the first three columns as being results for Treatment 1 and the second three as results for Treatment 2. The table would look something like this:

```
table <- stargazer(temp, type="html", summary=F)
```

The problem I have is that I cannot figure out how to add those identifiers for T1 and T2. I first tried `column.labels` in conjunction with `column.separate` but have since learned that those only work when using stargazer for actual regression output rather than just a plain data frame. Something like `dep.var.caption` would actually be preferable (I like the line separating this identifier and the column heads), but I think that too only works with pure regression output, and even still I can't find a way to do separate ones that each span multiple columns.

Any ideas of how I could make this work, or find a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't now much about stargazer, but strongly recommend using kableExtra when working with HTML/Latex tables in R.

**Solution using [`kableExtra`](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra):**

Generate example data:

```
a <- c(3, 0.5, 0.010, 4, 0.3, 0.271)
b <- c(10, 0.9, 0.021, 8, 0.5, 0.063)
temp <- data.frame(rbind(b, a))
colnames(temp) <- c("Coef", "SE", "p-value", "Coef", "SE", "p-value")
temp

  Coef  SE p-value Coef  SE p-value
b   10 0.9   0.021    8 0.5   0.063
a    3 0.5   0.010    4 0.3   0.271
```

Generate HTML table:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
kable(temp, format = "html", 
      row.names = FALSE,
      caption = "Way better than stargazer") %>%
    kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped",
                  full_width = TRUE) %>%
    add_header_above(c("alpha" = 3, "bravo" = 3))
```

[image]